# Can I push a URL into my application's 'history' when testing in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, testing, phpunit

I'm writing a test suite for a Laravel application. I'm making assertions against an endpoint that uses Laravel request validation to validate the user input. It automatically redirects the user back to the previous page.

```
$request->validate([
    'name'     => 'required',
    'email'    => 'required|email',
    'timeslot' => 'required'
]);
```

Currently, I am asserting that I if I post invalid data to this endpoint, I receive a redirect status code back. This is fine, but I would also like to assert, more specifically, that the user is redirected *back to the previous page*.

I feel that to test this condition properly, I need to somehow 'push' a URL into my test suite's/application's browser history, then assert that the redirect URL *is* that same URL.

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you share a bit more of your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a Laravel test, to simulate a previus Url, you use the `$this->from($url)` method provided by the `TestCase` class.

An example of it's usage:

```php
$this->from('/home')
     ->get('/profile')
     ->assertSee('User profile');
```

You may even use it with the `route()` or `url()` helper:

```php
$this->from(route('home'))
     ->get('/profile')
     ->assertSee('User profile');
```